# How to post a question if I can't find a matching tag?

Tags: support, tags

I'd like to post a question asking about apparent discrepancies in a series of fantasy novels (the *Deryni* series by Katherine Kurtz, to be specific).

I can not find an appropriate tag, and am not permitted to post the question without a tag.

How would I tag such a question?  Is there a way to post without a matching tag?

Or... is such a question off-topic, and, if so, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have over 300 reputation, so you should be [able to add new tags](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).  Just try typing the text of the tag (I'm guessing "deryni-series") into the tag area.

If you're getting an error, you might want to ask about that.  Sometimes a tag already exists, but is not spelled or punctuated the way you expect, and the system won't let you create a new tag that's too close to an existing one.

Note that if you're on the mobile site you won't be able to add tags.  (This is a frequent source of frustration for me.)  You can navigate to the regular site using the "full site" link at the right side of the footer, and you'll be able to add a new tag there.  (Thanks to Spencer for reminding me about this.)

Comment: Note that instead of trying to debug things in Meta, you might want to jump into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) which might work better.

Comment: You might want to note that tags only exist if they exist on a question. If after a day of being on no questions they will be deleted.

Comment: @DavidW No, this is exactly what meta is for. Information about how the site works should be preserved here, instead of in the constantly moving flow of chat. You might think this is obvious, or easy to figure out, or in the help centre, but if one person was confused enough about it to ask, then others will be too, so this meta can be useful in the future.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Indeed, many of us don't participate in Chat, so if you want to talk about how the site works, in ways that might be useful to others, *please* use meta.

Comment: @Kevin I was thinking more of how to effectively help _that person_ at _that time_; repeatedly editing the question and answer in turn to have a conversation seems slow, clunky and error-prone.  I have no problem at all with retrospectively updating the question and answer with a summary of the important points, but posting an answer that says "what do you see when you do X?" seems not very useful.